# How can I fix the update query for this BigQuery table schema?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data structure:

```
[
   {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "id",
      "type": "STRING"
   },
   {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "key",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "lifeid",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "monthly",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "thingtype",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "thingvalue",
        "type": "INTEGER"
      },
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "premium",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "provider",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "rank",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ],
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "provider",
        "type": "RECORD"
      },
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "someBool",
            "type": "BOOLEAN"
          },
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "code",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "description",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "listName",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ],
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "anotherBool",
            "type": "RECORD"
          },
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "caseid",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "dateCreated",
                "type": "TIMESTAMP"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "dateLastModified",
                "type": "TIMESTAMP"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "interviewTerminated",
                "type": "BOOLEAN"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "status",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ],
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "casedata",
            "type": "RECORD"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "hasAttachments",
            "type": "BOOLEAN"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "hasX",
            "type": "BOOLEAN"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "lifeId",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "lifeIdentifier",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "code",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "description",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "listName",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ],
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "status",
            "type": "RECORD"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "mibComplete",
            "type": "BOOLEAN"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "thingid",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "code",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "description",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "listname",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ],
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "name": "riskTypes",
            "type": "RECORD"
          }
        ],
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "randomcompany",
        "type": "RECORD"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "termlength",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "timestamp",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "things",
    "type": "RECORD"
  },
]
```

I am attempting to update `things` for a given `id` using:

```
UPDATE `table` SET things = things ||  [
        struct<key STRING, lifeid STRING, monthly STRING, thingtype STRING, thingvalue INTEGER, 
            provider struct<premium STRING, provider STRING, rank STRING>, 
            randomcompany struct< 
                someBool BOOLEAN,
                anotherBool struct<code STRING, description STRING, listName STRING>,
                casedata struct<caseid STRING, dateCreated STRING, dateLastModified STRING, interviewTerminated BOOLEAN, status STRING>,
                hasAttachments BOOLEAN,
                hasX BOOLEAN,
                lifeId STRING,
                lifeIdentifier STRING,
                status struct<code STRING, description STRING, listName STRING>,
                mibComplete BOOLEAN,
                thingid STRING,
                riskTypes array<struct<code STRING, description STRING, listName STRING>>
            >, 
            termlength STRING, timestamp TIMESTAMP>
        ('example key', 'example lifeid', 'example monthly', 'example thingtype', 4, 
            struct('example premium' as premium, 'example provider' as provider, 'example rank' as rank), 
                (true,
                    struct('a code' as code, 'a description' as description, 'a listName' as listname),
                    struct('6752' as caseid, NULL as dateCreated, NULL as dateLastModified, false as interviewTerminated, 'OPEN' as status),
                    false,
                    false,
                    'LV25APL37',
                    'LV25APL37',
                    struct('a code' as code, 'a description' as description, 'a listName' as listname),
                    false,
                    'ST11006752',
                    [struct('a code' as code, 'a description' as description, 'a listName' as listname)]
                ), 
                'example termlength', NULL
        )
    ]
WHERE id = '7PHh1dN0HdVGCAzIDIVkPWQ4GjI3';
```

This doesn't work and I get the error:

```
No matching signature for operator || for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, lifeid STRING, monthly STRING, ...>>, ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, lifeid STRING, monthly STRING, ...>>. Supported signatures: STRING || STRING; BYTES || BYTES; ARRAY || ARRAY at [1:77]
```

I am unable to find out what exactly is wrong due to the truncated error.  If I could see the full error I would be able to see which part of the update syntax is incorrect.  This would prevent me writing questions to Stack Overflow and enable me to fix the issue myself.  I heard that running the following in the console would give me the full error but it doesn't seem to work, only showing the same error:

`bq --format=prettyjson show -j project:US.bquxjob_...`

What is the correct syntax for an update here please?

Also, is there a way to debug issues like this, for example, seeing a full error.

When writing statements like this, what's the rule of thumb for aliases and when do I need to explicitly write `struct(` or `[struct(` in the second half of the query?  Surely the first half gives all the information about the types?

Lastly, am I missing the point here with BigQuery?  Should I break down the current data structure into different tables?  Surely the structure isn't so complex and should be easy to update?!

Comment: you need to make sure that concatenated arrays are of EXACT SAME schema! all names, types must be same! otherwise  - exactly that error comes up! In your previous two similar questions that I answered  - that was exactly way that resolved your problems. you need to apply same technic here! If still problem and you still will need help - you should provide kind of create table statement which will reproduce your data so we can play with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just quick shot - try below (I spotted two places where type was STRING but should be TIMESTAMP)

```
UPDATE `table` SET things = things ||  [
        struct<key STRING, lifeid STRING, monthly STRING, thingtype STRING, thingvalue INTEGER, 
            provider struct<premium STRING, provider STRING, rank STRING>, 
            randomcompany struct< 
                someBool BOOLEAN,
                anotherBool struct<code STRING, description STRING, listName STRING>,
                casedata struct<caseid STRING, dateCreated TIMESTAMP, dateLastModified TIMESTAMP, interviewTerminated BOOLEAN, status STRING>,
                hasAttachments BOOLEAN,
                hasX BOOLEAN,
                lifeId STRING,
                lifeIdentifier STRING,
                status struct<code STRING, description STRING, listName STRING>,
                mibComplete BOOLEAN,
                thingid STRING,
                riskTypes array<struct<code STRING, description STRING, listName STRING>>
            >, 
            termlength STRING, timestamp TIMESTAMP>
        ('example key', 'example lifeid', 'example monthly', 'example thingtype', 4, 
            struct('example premium' as premium, 'example provider' as provider, 'example rank' as rank), 
                (true,
                    struct('a code' as code, 'a description' as description, 'a listName' as listname),
                    struct('6752' as caseid, NULL as dateCreated, NULL as dateLastModified, false as interviewTerminated, 'OPEN' as status),
                    false,
                    false,
                    'LV25APL37',
                    'LV25APL37',
                    struct('a code' as code, 'a description' as description, 'a listName' as listname),
                    false,
                    'ST11006752',
                    [struct('a code' as code, 'a description' as description, 'a listName' as listname)]
                ), 
                'example termlength', NULL
        )
    ]
WHERE id = '7PHh1dN0HdVGCAzIDIVkPWQ4GjI3';
```